# Can't access properties of swift 4 class from objective-c

Tags: objective-c, properties, swift4

I've seen a lot of questions and answers on this, but none of them seem to cover or solve my situation.

I have a project originally written in Objc, and now, one by one, I'm replacing all classes with Swift 4 syntax.

My problem is, that I cannot access swift properties in my Objective C files.

This is what I have so far:

I have this one swift file, called MessagesViewController.swift that starts as follows:

```
@objc class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @objc var mailboxNumber:NSNumber = 0
        ...
```

Then, in there is the objc class "MessagesBoxController" that needs to access **mailboxNumber** in the prepareForSegue method:

So, in MessagesBoxController.h I import the generated interface header:

```
#import "myProduct-Swift.h"
```

and in MessagesBoxController.m I have this boilerplate method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    MessagesViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [_tv indexPathForSelectedRow];
    destViewController.mailboxNumber =selectedIndexPath.row+1;
}
```

So, the Swift class "MessagesViewController" is recognised fine; no complaints by the compiler whatsoever. Its properties though are not exposed:

auto complete doesn't suggest **mailboxNumber** and upon building the project, I get the error

> "Property 'mailboxNumber' not found on object of type
>   'MessagesViewController *'"

What part is missing to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

OK,
So, the basic setup is correct.
I ended up cleaning the project. I then got the message that "myProduct-Swift.h" could not be found.
Then I quit XCode and deleted the derived data. That helped.

Comment: I am still facing issue to access my Int & Bool from Swift to objective-C ... and getting this error : *Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C* , Any suggetion ? .. I have used same header "MyProject-Swift.h.